# Is Quarkus optimized for docker container runtime or it is just for Kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, docker-swarm, quarkus

As described at Quarkus website that it is "Kubernetes native Java framework".

Does that means it cannot be used for other Docker Orchestration platforms like DockerSwarm ? or it is just only optimized for K8S ?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you build a [docker image](https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image-guide#creating-a-container), nothing stops you for using it with the container orchestration platform of your choice such as Docker Swarm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then, the title "K8S native Java framework" is little bit misleading. What do you think?

Comment: Quarkus can generate Kubernetes configuration automatically, that's how I interpret it ^^

Comment: @SoufianeSakhi How so? The Maven Archetypes/Plugins create those, not Quarkus

Comment: @cricket_007 I think it relies on a Java annotation processor to generate the Kubernetes configuration. You can read more about it here: https://quarkus.io/guides/kubernetes

Comment: @SoufianeSakhi Thanks, but that looks like it is scanning the META-INF manifest for some labels, which is different than annotation processing

Comment: The implementation that takes care of generating the actual Kubernetes resources is provided by dekorate, a Java annotation processors.

Comment: @SoufianeSakhi Okay, so what would it take to do something similar for other orchestrators? (Swarm/Marathon/Aurora/Nomad/ whatever comes out after the hype cycle of k8s is over)?