# Quarkus on Hashicorp Nomad

Tags: java, docker, marathon, quarkus, nomad

Quarkus is described as [a *Kubernetes Native* Java stack](https://quarkus.io/), which I think is unfair marketting hype given that there is no code specific in it for Kubernetes, to my knowledge (ignoring deployment scripts and Maven plugins, etc).

Anyone tried launching it in a different Docker orchestrator? Specifically, [Hashicorp Nomad](https://nomadproject.io/)? How about [Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/)? Bonus points for Swarm, of course.

If this is possible, should the documentation be updated to remove such marketing words as "Kubernetes native"?

Comment: I run it successfully on Docker-Swarm. Now regarding K8S naming, I asked this question before under this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58154184/is-quarkus-optimized-for-docker-container-runtime-or-it-is-just-for-kubernetes. Check the answer and comments.

Comment: That's what I thought, but would like a contributor to chime in here.

Comment: As per @Gunnar, I know it works in OpenShift fine...

Comment: I think it describes the focus of the project to design something that fits natively on Kubernetes, in a time people are more concerned with low resource usage (small Docker images, low memory usage, fast startup, comparable to golang or nodejs applications that traditional Java Application servers and Spring Boot couldn't match, although they perform better in the long run because of JIT and better GC performance)

Comment: @JohannesB Nothing about k8s is focused on low resource usage. In fact, k3s uses far less resources, and Nomad (plus Consul) are even less (haven't actually verified that). So again, why "Kubernetes native" instead of every other branded CNCF project of "cloud native" (even though vast majority of those _also_ state they are explicitly reliant on k8s api-server or CRDs) or just simply "container native"?  Outside of CRDs and PVC, there's mainly just the api-server and a pluggable scheduler... CSI and CNI are external from k8s. Moby / containerd + other container specs are as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you may be a little bit right about the marketing hype as you call it, although I do not understand why Quarkus would need to tie itself to Kubernetes in order to call itself a Kubernetes Native Java Stack. As you seem well aware:

Kubernetes has become the de-facto standard container orchestration solution with its many certified implementations, like the ones mentioned [in your link from the comments](https://www.cncf.io/certification/software-conformance/). According to many opinions, it has won the war on container orchestration.

The original group starting the Quarkus project (i.e. Red Hat) stated:

> The goal of Quarkus is to make Java a leading platform in Kubernetes
>   and serverless environments while offering developers a unified
>   reactive and imperative programming model to optimally address 
>   a wider range of distributed application architectures.

Red Hat has a invested/sponsored the related technologies like (in random order):

1. Linux (through Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
2. OpenShift platform
3. IcedTea (Open Source build software to compile the OpenJDK sources from Sun/Oracle)
4. An Open Source new Java Garbage Collector [Shenandoah](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2888189/red-hat-shenandoah-boosts-java-garbage-collection.html) for the HotSpot VM that closes part of the gap with Azul's Zing VM and C4 Garbage Collector (ahead-of-time compilation is another)
5. Java Application Servers (JBoss AS / WildFly)
6. And also other great Java applications like, Keycloak [that will be powered by Quarkus](https://www.keycloak.org/2019/10/keycloak-x)

And Quarkus is just one of the ways they are trying (quite successfully) to apply new technological advancements in Java (like the module system, ahead-of-time-compilation) as implemented in both OpenJDK and GraalVM to improve the integration with modern hosting and deployment solutions, like Kubernetes. For more see e.g.: [these blogs](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/tag/graalvm/)

Some of the more simple, lower level changes necessary to improve the behaviour of the Java Virtual machines are related to certain Linux features (like cgroups) and [have already been fixed](https://blog.softwaremill.com/docker-support-in-new-java-8-finally-fd595df0ca54) in the past.

However, one of the greatest challenges to get existing Java applications to run on GraalVM's Substrate VM for native images is that it does not (yet) support all of the features that popular Java frameworks (e.g. Spring and Hibernate) rely on, as documented in [this long list](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/substratevm/LIMITATIONS.md)

So, as I understand, in order to fix that [quoting from here](https://quarkus.io/blog/why-graalvm-19-2/) they developed Quarkus:

> [to work] equally well on any JVM and as GraalVM native image executables. And you can build native images with no hassle, on your side.

---

Is this all about marketing? No, I don't buy that. I think it is about having a clear vision and goal by the projects leadership.
I'll give you that it would be a great addition to more clearly describe which platforms are considered a compatible target, have had some kind of formal testing, and are thus "supported;" but for that kind of information you are probably looking at formal support contracts on Quarkus and more importantly: GraalVM (probably from Red Hat, Oracle, IBM and friends).